# Deriving Stream-Velocity out of a DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, hydrology-toolset

I'm using Arc GIS Toolbox Hydrology...everything works fine. Moreover, it is possible to derive the potential stream velocity just out of the DEM? Informations about rainfall, infiltration, hydraulic radius or surface roughness are not available and the project should be kept easy!

I need streamclasses like: fast velocity, slow velocity and standing water.

Does anybody have an idea how to derive such a classification just out of a DEM?

Comment: You could always try to extract something from the slope, but you'd need to define categories based on that which matches fast, slow and standing water. Remember though, the DEM (if originating from a laser scan) only captures the water surface. If this is a problem depends on what scale you are doing this analysis, and of course what you want to get out of it in the end.